# SMP 3.0 SDK : Agentry Toolkit : How to use Agentry toolkit in your app?

Tags: sap-smp

I am new for SAP Mobile Platform (SMP 3.0).

As per my basic research, I came to know that 'Agentry Toolkit' is one of the component of SMP 3.0 SDK. I installed SMP 3.0 SDK.

Can anyone help me to describe **what is actually 'Agentry Toolkit' & How to use it in app (Hello World App) ?.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to remember is that SAP Mobile Platform (SMP) is a server which hosts and manages a variety of mobile application types. The mobile platform has to support a number of 'legacy' technologies e.g. Sybase mobile business objects etc.
SAP acquired a company called Syclo (it has a number of products the most common one is called Work Manager).

The SDK is a set of tools that developers mainly use to develop and deploy mobile applications. It contains a number of SDKs so that developers can integrate with the various mobile "components" that run on the mobile platform.

The Agentry Toolkit is a plugin to Eclipse which allows you to create, edit and modify Agentry applications.

[image]

You can of course create an application from scratch and build a "hello world" using this.